# emission shader casting shadows - problem not solved

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

There is already a post about it in [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2622/is-it-possible-for-a-emission-shader-not-to-cast-shadows), but the problem is not solved, in fact it is not a solution to the problem. What can we do to avoid shadows from emission shaders?

There's a similar post about it in [here](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?337423-How-to-disable-shadows-for-2-out-of-3-light-emitting-meshes), and still the problem is not solved, and it seems: LIGHT PATHS CANNOT BE USED FOR MESH LIGHTS.
Here is a blend file that contains a simple experiment that demonstrates that the aforementioned solution in the first link does not work:
[image]

**So, how do we avoid mesh lights to cast shadows?**

Comment: Is this what you want?
https://snapr.pw/i/4ce8554edd.png

Comment: @Ezra, yes, how did you obtain it?

Comment: I used the diffuse factor of a light path node to mix the diffuse shader of the cube with a transparent  shader. Using the reflection output of the light path node gives the same result, so you might need to use both for more complex scenes.

Comment: @Ezra, do you mean the 'Is Shadow Ray' factor of light path - it won't work with 'Is Diffuse Ray'. Also, this would have to be applied to all materials and would have the effect of removing shadows from all light sources rather than individually. One of the linked wuestions indicates disabling the shadows from all but one of the sources.

Comment: Try this:
https://snapr.pw/i/1446ab92dd.png

Comment: @Ezra, it doesn't really work

Comment: @BumbleBee it's weird, because it works when I try it. If you want a solid solution, I would go for using multiple layers.

Comment: @Ezra, yes, I've found using multiple render layers is the only solution and then we must composite them together.

Comment: Cycles doesn't have a light group solution, do you happen to know an addon as such?

Answer (score 1):

In your particular example case you could replace your emitter object with an area lamp - this does support suppressing shadows as shown :

3d View :
[image: 3d View]

Cast Shadow disabled :
[image: Without shadow]

Cast Shadow enabled :
[image: With shadow]

However, I don't think it's possible to suppress shadows from mesh-based emission materials due to the nature of the physics based rendering. ie, if you're suppressing light from emission surfaces then what about light reflected from a glossy surface - that could also cast shadows - as could light from a diffuse surface (albeit much more subtle, but it would still be a shadow).

Comment: I deliberately was forming a simple scene here. To point out that the shadows do form

Comment: Though, what you said is true

Comment: I did think it was deliberately simplified. Do you have a specific practical situation in mind where the area lamp wouldn't be a suitable substitute?

Comment: I think emitters are particularly good for fill lights, but they cast shadows. Spots are better for casting sharp shadows. Emitters behave more like those metal sheets that emit in uni direction.

Comment: The area lamp appears to produce pretty much identical results when compared to a rectangular mesh emitter - with the exception that the intensity for an area lamp is for the whole lamp whereas for an emitter it's per unit area (so double the size of emitter would produce an output 4 times stronger). The only reason I can see for using a mesh emitter is where the geometry of the emitter is significant - eg, modelling the filament of a light bulb - in which case you'd be looking for realism, including casting shadows. For general illumination, the area lamp is surely the better option.